# Add calendar event via freeform text w/documented, unambiguous syntax?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, calendar

Is there any way (probably thirdparty app, assuming it's not some secret hidden option in CM10.1) to add calendar events on a Galaxy S3 running 4.2/CM10.1[RC5 at this moment] with a syntax like:

```
on Monday [or "next Wednesday" or "July 7"]
at 3pm
call 3055551212,99988877#
re call with somebody important
for 30m
notify 10m,14h
```

via some method that's actually

- documented somewhere,
- has deterministic & unambiguous syntax, and
- Allows you to set the 'location' field of the calendar event to a clickable phone number that includes comma (pause), additional digits, and trailing '#'?

Over the years, and with various ROMs I've installed, I've seen "quick input" methods like this seemingly come and go at random, with basically undocumented syntax and unreliable handling of "clickable phone number as location that includes pause & extension#".

I *know* that someone, somewhere, SOMEHOW, has to have actually gotten this *right*... but *who*? (Or, where's the option, what's it called, and where is it documented)?

Comment: Looks like voice input for *Google Now* to me :) Honestly: As *Google Now* takes that as voice input, it will have to recognize the text, convert it to "ASCII", and then add it to the calendar. So somewhere along these lines, it's already happening.

Comment: Ugh. I'm not a fan of voice input, and recoil against anything that uses "natural language". I hate ambiguity. To me, things like "Google Now" feel like a warped, real-life 80s text adventure game where you're forced to play "try to outsmart the parser", and attempts to be explicit end up confusing the parser completely.

Comment: *LOL* You definitly made your point, Bitbang3r. A while ago I tried to figure out those things with Voice Search – your description looks like you were sitting next to me then :) // Back to topic: How shall this input come to your device: SMS, Mail? I'm thinking of *Tasker*, which e.g. could parse such a text file, and the rules would be up to you. Might be a bit tricky to set up, but should be possible.